# how to remove the .net framework launch condition from .msi setup?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I am creating windows installer (.MSI package) for my project using visual studio 2010. I want to remove the launch condition for .net framework as I am manually performing the same check in my custom action events. For my project the “Delete” option for “.net framework” launch condition is showing disabled. So, I am not able to delete it.

I have tried following solutions:

1)  I have installed orca3.1. I have open my .msi with in the ORCA and searched for the “VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions” word. I have deleted all the references for the same and saved the .msi file for the project. When I try to install the same on client machine it is giving following error during installation:

> Error 1001. Error 1001.
>   InstallUtilLib.dll: Unknown error The
>   description for Event ID 11001 from
>   source MsiInstaller cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this
>   event is not installed on your local
>   computer or the installation is
>   corrupted. You can install or repair
>   the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event:

> Product: SoundBite -- Error 1001.
>   Error 1001. InstallUtilLib.dll:
>   Unknown error. (NULL) (NULL) (NULL)
>   (NULL)

2)  I have open the “.vdproj” file and try to remove references for the launch conditions and bootstrap condition for .net framework. When I tried to build the setup, it is getting added automatically.
Can anyone help me to short out this issue?

Answer (score 4):

- Right-Click on Setup Project.
- Properties Menu.
- Click Prerequisites button.
- Uncheck .NET Framework from Prerequisites or disable all Prerequisites with uncheck "Create setup program to install prerequisite  components"

Answer (score 2):

I managed to remove the launch condition with Orca dropping the unique row in the `_VsdLaunchCondition` table.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this information in MSDN: [How to disable the default launch condition for the .net framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msiclickonce/archive/2009/12/21/how-to-disable-the-default-launch-condition-for-the-net-framework-in-a-visual-studio-setup-and-deployment-project.aspx)?